# Question about cross product of images of linear transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-transformations, cross-product

I'm reading "Differential Geometry: Curves and Surfaces" of Manfredo Carmo, and this part in the book confuses me(page 166):

> Suppose that $N: S \rightarrow S^2$ is the Gauss map of regular surface $S$ into unit sphere. We know that for each $p \in S$, $dN_p$ is a self-adjoint linear mapping. Suppose that $\{w_1, w_2\}$ is a basis in $T_p(S)$, then we have:
>   $$dN_p(w_1) \times dN_p(w_2) = \det(dN_p)(w_1 \times w_2) = Kw_2 \times w_2$$

So the part confuses me is the equation $$dN_p(w_1) \times dN_p(w_2) = \det(dN_p)(w_1 \times w_2)$$

I did search around, and found this equation for cross product:
$$Ma \times Mb = \det(M)(M^T)^{-1} (a \times b)$$

So, to make the mentioned equation right, we need to have $(M^T)^{-1} = I$, which I don't think it's true in general. Can anyone help me explain this? I really appreciate.

Comment: if any reader finds a reference for that formula, it would be helpful

Comment: There is something relevant for *orthogonal* (not self-adjoint) linear maps, but it applies only to maps on all of $\Bbb R^3$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783522/cross-product-of-image-of-self-adjoint-operator/3784246#3784246) for a correct solution. I've also explained the cross-product formula you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition you've arrived at is exactly the "self-adjoint linear mapping" condition in the passage.

Comment: Oh, I see. Seem like my formula is wrong. It should be $Ma \times Mb = \det(M)(M^T)^{-1}(a \times b)$. Thanks

Comment: This answer is total nonsense.